# windows-7 hdmi audio

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Vista/7: Managing multiple audio playback devices](https://superuser.com/questions/22996/windows-vista-7-managing-multiple-audio-playback-devices)

Hello,

I am using windows 7 and here is my question :

Is there a way for windows to swtich my audio output to HDMI automatically when a HDMI cable is plugged in ? Right now, to switch the audio output I need to go specify my default output to HDMI everytime I plug it in and set it back to speakers once I plug it out.

Cheers !

Comment: Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/22996/windows-vista-7-managing-multiple-audio-playback-devices

Answer (score 0):

found an answer :
[How do I manage multiple audio playback devices on Windows Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/22996/windows-vista-7-managing-multiple-audio-playback-devices)

I tried searching before but I wasn't using the right tags.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to check is, if your graphics card even outputs sound through the HDMI port. I've heard of issues where the HDMI  port only outputs video or that you have to connect an audio cable to the card to get sound through the HDMI port.