# How can I make HDMI sound work consistently when plugging in after booting up?

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

When I plug an HDMI monitor into my laptop (running Windows 7), the image always works as expected, but the sound usually does not work. Based on suggestions found while trawling support forums [links forthcoming] I have tried:

- testing the HDMI monitor and cable with another device (it works consistently)
- switching on the monitor before plugging in, switching on the monitor after plugging in
- setting the HDMI device to the default sound device
- setting the HDMI device to the default communication device
- both of the above
- ticking and unticking "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"
- logging out and in again
- changing HDMI settings in the BIOS (no such settings in Aptio Setup Utility on my machine)

Booting up with the cable plugged in works consistently. The problem occurs (intermittently, but most of the time) when plugging the monitor after booting up.

I am tired of turning it off and on again. How can I make plugging in an HDMI sound device work consistently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I manage multiple audio playback devices on Windows Vista/7?](http://superuser.com/questions/22996/how-do-i-manage-multiple-audio-playback-devices-on-windows-vista-7)

Answer (score 0):

According to a user on this forum, disabling his (integrated) Realtek High Definition Audio in Device Manager fixed the issue.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/395455-33-sound-stopped-working-hdmi

Comment: I think this might be better off as a comment, since it doesn't actually show what to do, and links to somewhere else.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Steven has indicated everything the user on the forum indicated worked for him.  The suggestion is a single step, you disable a device in device manager, beyond showing a screenshot of random instance device manager not sure if there is a need to eleborate.  Everything from the suggestion is currently in the answer.